# action-btn needs two clicks to perform the click

Tags: javascript, button, action, var, getelementbyid

```
var button = document.getElementById("action-btn");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var container = document.getElementById("mostrarc");
        
    if(container.style.display === "none") {
        container.style.display = "block"
    } else {
        container.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

need to click twice for the function to happen

the purpose of this button is that when clicking a new div will appear, I would like to change the title of the button after clicking

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML. Also, avoid using the `.style` property of DOM elements as it creates an inline style, which should be avoided whenever possible. Instead just add/remove pre-made CSS classes. In your case, you could just toggle the use of a "hidden" type class.

Comment: This question would be better if it included a runnable stack snippet.

Comment: toggle a class..... save yourself the headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it has to do with the initial state of the `container` element. As I mentioned in the comments, avoid setting the `style` property and instead use CSS classes, which makes the JS code so much simpler.

```js
// Get your DOM references just once, not every time a function runs.
var button = document.getElementById("action-btn");
var container1 = document.getElementById("mostrarc1");
var container2 = document.getElementById("mostrarc2");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Just toggle the use of the class which removes the need for if/then
  container1.classList.toggle("hidden");
  container2.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
#mostrarc1 {
  width:75px; height:75px; background: #e0e0e0; margin:25px;
}
#mostrarc2 {
  width:75px; height:75px; background: #ff0; margin:25px;
}

/* This class is applied in the HTML so the element will initially be hidden.
   But, when the button is clicked, the use of the class will be toggled.  */
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="action-btn">Show/Hide</button>
<div id="mostrarc1" class="hidden">Container Area 2</div>
<div id="mostrarc2">Container Area 1</div>
```

Comment: I would like to change a div, clicking will show the hidden div, clicking again returns the previous div

Comment: @viniwest This technique accomplishes that. Just add a second `div` that has its `display` property set as the opposite of the first one and upon clicking of the button, toggle both. I'll update the answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

As a **counter-example** to your claim that you *"need to click twice for the function to happen"*, I present this runnable snippet, which uses your code verbatim, and only needs to be clicked once.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("action-btn");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var container = document.getElementById("mostrarc");
        
    if(container.style.display === "none") {
        container.style.display = "block"
    } else {
        container.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="action-btn">Action</button>
<div id="mostrarc">Example</div>
```

**If there is CSS** that applies to the style of your element causing it to be **initially hidden** with `display: none`, then you will get the unexpected behaviour you are likely experiencing.  Initially the CSS is defining the style, and then after you set `.style.display = "none"` now you have an inline style as well as the CSS rule.  The inline style will be created (if none existed before) and will supersede the CSS style rule, even if the style change is the same.  This version seemingly "needs to be clicked twice" initially.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("action-btn");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var container = document.getElementById("mostrarc");
    
    console.log(container.style);    
    if(container.style.display === "none") {
        container.style.display = "block"
    } else {
        container.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```css
#mostrarc {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button id="action-btn">Action</button>
<div id="mostrarc">Example</div>
```

What's happening here is that there is initially no inline style so `container.style.display` is the empty string, and so `container.style.display === "none"` is false, and your code then explicitly sets `container.style.display = "none"` and stays hidden.  But after this first click, now you *do* have an inline style, and toggling will behave as expected.

Answer (score -1):

So you want the button to toggle between show/hide?

```js
const
  button = document.getElementById('action-btn'),
  container = document.getElementById('mostrarc');
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const isHidden = container.style.display === 'none';
  if (isHidden) {
    container.style.display = 'block';
    button.innerText = 'Hide';
  } else {
    container.style.display = 'none';
    button.innerText = 'Show';
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="action-btn">Hide</button>
<div id="mostrarc">Some visible content...</div>
```

A better way to approach this is either a style:

```js
const
  button = document.getElementById('action-btn'),
  container = document.getElementById('mostrarc');
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const isHidden = container.classList.contains('hidden');
  if (isHidden) {
    container.classList.remove('hidden');
    button.innerText = 'Hide';
  } else {
    container.classList.add('hidden');
    button.innerText = 'Show';
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<button id="action-btn">Hide</button>
<div id="mostrarc">Some visible content...</div>
```

Or a data-attribute:

```js
const
  button = document.getElementById('action-btn'),
  container = document.getElementById('mostrarc');
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const isHidden = container.hasAttribute('data-hidden');
  if (isHidden) {
    container.removeAttribute('data-hidden');
    button.innerText = 'Hide';
  } else {
    container.setAttribute('data-hidden', '');
    button.innerText = 'Show';
  }
});
```

```css
div[data-hidden] { display: none; }
```

```html
<button id="action-btn">Hide</button>
<div id="mostrarc">Some visible content...</div>
```

Comment: All of these suggestions are overkill and some go against best practices of avoiding inline styles. See my answer for the simplest solution that conforms to best practices.

Comment: Instead of showing the text, I would like to change a div, clicking will show the hidden div, clicking again returns the previous div

Comment: @viniwest that's what each of the three snippets do above; they toggle the display of the div.